# HTML/CSS Fixed positioning causing overlapping divs

Tags: html, css, web, position, css-position

I am trying to create 2 side banners (left and right) with fixed positioning, and a centered container for the content.

[image]

The problem is that when minimizing the screen, the 2 side banners cover the centered container. I need a CSS solution to set the minimum width of the view to 860px; after which, the window becomes scrollable and divs do not overlap. The perfect solution is:

[image]

The HTML I am using is as such:

```
<div class="left" style="position:fixed; height:100%; background-color:#7fb4dd; top:43px; left:0px; width:180px;">
</div>

<div class="center" style="margin:100px 180px 0 180px;">
        <div style="width:100%;">
                        <div style="width:500px; margin:0 auto;">
                        </div>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="right" style="position:fixed; height:100%; background-color:#7fb4dd; top:43px; right:0px; width:180px;">
</div>
```

The above code prevents the left bar from overlapping the center container; but the problem is still present with the right bar.

This is a fiddle of the code: [preview](http://jsfiddle.net/eFY7h/)

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: I have added a fiddle in the bottom of the question asked.

Comment: After looking at your fiddle you made, I strongly recommend to make your css in it's own file. Inline styles is not the way to go especially with a responsive website.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the three DIVs in a wrapping DIV and set the `min-width` to prevent the overlap. This prevents it from getting narrower than the three columns. Add up the widths, set that as the minimum.

Comment: @ BruteForce You can also use javascript's `if` statements to add this depending on which page they are on. (if all do not need this style)

Comment: @Diodeus I tried this suggestion, but it did not solve the problem. The right div is still covering the center wrapper.
The scroll bar is appearing but not preventing the right bar issue.

Comment: @Josh can you clarify how can I use the javascript

Comment: I'm making you a fiddle, one second please.

Comment: @JoshPowell this would be great. I have created a fiddle myself (http://jsfiddle.net/eFY7h/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are in is because of `position: fixed;` since that object is taken out of the workflow the other objects can't push it away. I was able to get a nice and fully responsive layout to work. (Let me know how it is)

> Fixed positioned elements are removed from the normal flow. The
>   document and other elements behave like the fixed positioned element
>   does not exist.
>
> Fixed positioned elements can overlap other elements.

**Updated answer to better suit his needs** ([JSFIDDLE, remove the show, in the url, to see code](http://jsfiddle.net/sb2J6/16/show))

Okay what I am doing here is using css `media queries` to change the layout.

Here is the html,

```
<div class="wrap">
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <section class="lSide"></section>
    <section class="rSide"></section>
</div>
```

Now the media query,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .content {
    width: 90%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .lSide, .rSide {
      position: relative;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add this to your `head` on your `html` file,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;">
```

**OLD answer**

The CSS, ([JSFIDDLE, remove the show to see code](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/sb2J6/10/show))

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: tan;
}

.wrap.active {
    min-width: 750px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background: brown;
    z-index: 101;
}

.lSide {
    background: #3b3b3b;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 20%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80%;
}

.content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 20%;
}

.rSide {
    background: #3b3b3b;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 20%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80%;
}

.rSide.active {
    display: none;
}
```

The JS, (updated)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < '750') {
        $('.wrap, .rSide').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.wrap, .rSide').removeClass('active');  
    }
});
```

One solution I have, refer to fiddle next to css, is to remove the right side when a screen size is to small.

Comment: What you did is great.
As you said, the right side banner is harder to control. I would really appreciate if you could solve the problem or give any suggestions.

Comment: Good suggestion.
I was testing it on a mobile device, what was showing overlapping issues.

Comment: Ahh if this is for mobile devices then I strongly recommend you look into `media queries`. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: @BruteForce Look at my updated answer for the best option to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure HTML/CSS solution for you , tell me if it is not exactly what you needed.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height: 1.5em;
}

b{font-size: 110%;}
em{color: red;}

#topsection{
background: #EAEAEA;
height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
}

#topsection h1{
margin: 0;
padding-top: 15px;
}

#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

#contentcolumn{
margin: 0 200px 0 230px; /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 RightColumnWidth 0 LeftColumnWidth*/

background-color : red;
width : 400px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
}

#leftcolumn{
float: left;
width: 200px; /*Width of left column*/
margin-left: -100%;
background: #C8FC98;
}

#rightcolumn{
float: left;
width: 200px; /*Width of right column*/
margin-left: -200px; /*Set left marginto -(RightColumnWidth)*/
background: #FDE95E;
}

#footer{
clear: left;
width: 100%;
background: black;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
}

.innertube{

margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
margin-top: 0;


height : 700px;
}


.innertubetop{
margin: 10px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
margin-top: 0;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer" style = "min-width : 800px;"> <!-- this will be sum of width of all three columns-->

<div id="topsection"><div class="innertubetop"><h1>Hello iam navigation bar</h1></div></div>

<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="contentcolumn">
<div class="innertube"><b>Center Column </b></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="leftcolumn">
<div class="innertube"><b>Left Column: <em>200px</em></b></div>

</div>

<div id="rightcolumn">
<div class="innertube"><b>Right Column: <em>200px</em></b></div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```